# C: Free temporary array produced by malloc-function

Tags: c, malloc, free

I have a c function that produces my a int array using malloc. It works quiet well and I think it isn't really important what it does because the problem doesn't really have anything to do with that. (In this case it calculates the numbers to a given int and base). I need this array temporary in a function, which might be a sub function of a sub function of a ... (you got the idea, point this function can be used several times) and before the return I would like to run free, but it doesn't work. Here is a testing code (it sorts an array of ints to the amount of ones in their binary representation using qsort (yes I know could have calculated the results more directly, but the point is the probleme I run into when trying to run free (here comment out in function ones))):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int values[] = { 88, 56, 100, 2, 25, 0, 15};
int * baseString(int u, int base);
int abs(int a);
int ones(int a);

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
   return ones(*(int*)a)>ones(*(int*)b);
}

int main()
{
   int n;

   printf("Before sorting the list is: \n");
   for( n = 0 ; n < 7; n++ ) 
   {
      printf("%d ", values[n]);
   }

   qsort(values, 7, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);

   printf("\nAfter sorting the list is: \n");
   for( n = 0 ; n < 7; n++ ) 
   {   
      printf("%d (Ones=%d) ", values[n], ones(values[n]));
   }
   printf("\n");
   return(0);
}

int abs(int a){
    return (a<0)? a*-1:a;
}

int* baseString(int u, int base){
    int* r=malloc(sizeof(int));
    r[0]=base;
    r[1]=1;
    if(base<2){
        r[2]=-1;
        return r;
    }
    int negativ=0;
    if(u<0){
        u=abs(u);
        negativ=1;
    }
    int i=2;
    do{
        int ur=u%base;
        r[i]=ur;
        u/=base;
        i++;
    }while(u>0);
    r[1]=i-1;
    if(negativ){
        r[1]=-r[1];
    }
    return r;
}

int ones(int a){
    int* ai=baseString(a, 2);
    int a1=1;
    for(int i=2; i<abs(ai[1]); i++){
       if(ai[i]==1){
           a1++;
       }
   }
   if(!a){
       a1=0;
   }
   //free(ai);
   return a1;
}
```

PS: I am quiet sure this thread is duplicate of some tread somewhere, but I didn't found it.

Comment: `abs` function already exist in <stdlib.h>

Comment: `int* r=malloc(sizeof(int));` `r` has only one  element.

Comment: It.. "doesn't work"?

Comment: I wasn't aware that abs was in the stdlib file. I thought it was in the math.h and for some reason this harder to bind in while compiling.  On my (virtual) ubuntu -lm or  -L/path/to/lib -lm doesn't work, eventhough the whereis returns usr/include for math.

Answer (score 1):

The key problem here appears to an ABW (Array Bounds Write). In the `baseString` function, you are actually allocating memory which is equivalent to the size of 1 integer, but are trying to access it like an array in `r[1],r[2], r[i]` etc, which results in write to memory which technically doesn't belong to you.

The code snippet in your code corresponds to

```
int* r=malloc(sizeof(int));
r[0]=base;
r[1]=1; //ABW here
if(base<2){
    r[2]=-1; //ABW here
    return r;
}

   do{
        int ur=u%base;
        r[i]=ur; //ABW here
        u/=base;
        i++;
    }while(u>0);
```

This might lead to undefined behavior at any point of time in your code. In your case, it seems to be affecting `free` as the memory overwrite may have messed up with the internal book keeping data of malloc and free implementation.

Comment: There is no "might" about it.   The examples you point out DO exhibit undefined behaviour.   Undefined behaviour does not mean a crash.   It means anything is allowed to happen - a crash is just one of the possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your problem is actually quite simple.

In your `baseString()` function, the first three lines are

```
int* r=malloc(sizeof(int));
r[0]=base;
r[1]=1;
```

The `malloc()` dynamically allocates a single `int`, or an array with one element.  The `r[1] = 1` modifies the second element of that array which has one element.

The result of that is undefined behaviour.   A common symptom of running off the end of an array like this is corrupting memory in your program, such as that used internally by `malloc()` and `free()` to keep track of allocated and released memory.  Which would explain your problem.

Make sure you allocate the number of elements needed.   For example, if 10 elements are needed, `malloc(10*sizeof(int))`.    You need to work out the number needed, since dynamically arrays will not magically grow to get the number of elements needed.

I haven't look further, so there may be other problems.   But this one is pretty glaring.

It is also a good idea to check that `malloc()` actually succeeds.  It returns `NULL` if it fails.

Comment: Ok I need at least 3 this would be malloc(int*3), but I thought not knowing how big the array is going to get is the whole point of malloc (ok in this case it could only be 34 (largest int in binary), but what do I do if I don't know this?). And how is it that the rest of my code works?

Comment: The point of `malloc()` (and operator `new`) is (typically) that the amount of memory needed is not known until the program is run.   If the amount of memory was known before the program is run, other techniques could be used and the compiler could handle initialisation and release.

Comment: Ok but this still mean I would have to know the maximum amount of memory I could endup needing. What if I don't? Sure I could run the programm one time dry and counting up how much space I need but that is not really practical is it?

Comment: It is sometimes practical, sometimes not.   But if you are using dynamic memory allocation, it is your responsibility to allocate what is needed, before you need it.   If you haven't allocated enough, reallocate more.   Use of `malloc()` allows you flexibility of how much - since the need can be left undetermined until the program is run - but doesn't relieve you of responsibility for working out how much you need.    Allocating an array of one element, and then using it like an array of three elements, abrogates your responsibility.

Comment: Is there a function that could make it work? Realmoc or Callmoc?

Comment: If by "make it work", you mean "implement some magic so the programmer does not have to worry about how much memory is allocated", then no.   If you mean ability to resize an allocated block, then `realloc()` can be used to resize a block returned by `malloc()`.  But one input to `realloc()` is the new required size - which still needs to be computed.